# Javascript character count

Tags: javascript, html, character

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/67XDq/1/

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr id="rq17">
    <td class='qnum'>17.</td>
    <td class='qtext'>Questions? <i>Maximum of 500 characters - <input style="color:red;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;" readonly type="text" name="q17length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="500"> characters left</i><br/>
              <textarea 
                 onKeyDown="textCounter(document.frmSurvey.q17,document.frmSurvey.q17length,500);"
                 onKeyUp="textCounter(document.frmSurvey.q17,document.frmSurvey.q17length,500)" 
                 class="scanwid" name="q17" id="q17" rows="5" cols="">
              </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
    else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
```

For some reason, which I am completely missing, this doesn't seem to be working as intended.

It should limited the number of characters in the `textarea` and also countdown the number within the `label` but it is doing neither.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Have you debugged each line to see if it contains what you expect it to contain?

Comment: Where's the jQuery in this question?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work at all. You need to select "no wrap (head)" and then you need to make sure the `<form>` tag is in the HTML.

Comment: see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/67XDq/7/

Comment: Apols - there was additional jQuery but I removed - forgot to remove from the title.  Added information about what isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two issues in the fiddle

- no form element
- script mode was onload, which means that window object didnt have `textCounter` function

see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/67XDq/7/, markup:

```
<tr id="rq17">
   <td class='qnum'>17.</td>
   <td class='qtext'>
    Questions? <i>Maximum of 500 characters - 
    <input style="color:red;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;" readonly="readonly" type="text" id='q17length' name="q17length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="500" /> characters left</i>
    <br />
    <textarea 
          onKeyDown="textCounter(this,'q17length',500);"
          onKeyUp="textCounter(this,'q17length',500)" 
          class="scanwid" name="q17" id="q17" rows="5" cols=""></textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and code

```
function textCounter(field, cnt, maxlimit) {         
  var cntfield = document.getElementById(cnt)   
  if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
  else
    cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

Comment: having var cntfield = document.getElementById(cnt) in the event handler is terribly inefficient. thanks for the answer anyways, it still helped!

Comment: @AlexDaro sshhhh of course it is. But if you know this you wouldn't go with such solution in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

CHange your html to remove all that onkey stuff

```
<tr id="rq17">
  <td class='qnum'>17.</td>
  <td class='qtext'>Questions? <i>Maximum of 500 characters - <input id="charsLeft" style="color:red;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;" readonly type="text" name="q17length" size="3" maxlength="3" value="500"> characters left</i><br/><textarea class="scanwid" name="q17" id="q17" rows="5" cols="" maxlength="500"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript is this:

```
 $("#q17").keyup(function() {
    $('#charsLeft').val(500 - $(this).val().length);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67XDq/11/

Comment: Maybe he should just include jQuery in his project and reap the rewards

Comment: Just for adding event handler and `document.getElementById` alias? Regardless of that, OP starter might not be able to use jquery for some reason.

Comment: OP said himself in comments that he used jQuery but go ahead and use getElementById til the cows come home

Comment: Thanks Tom - appreciated - will look at a jQuery solution in the future.

Answer (score 1):

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/67XDq/15/

**modified the function:**

```
function textCounter(field, cntfield, maxlimit) {        
    if (document.getElementById(field).value.length > maxlimit) {
        // if too long...trim it!
        document.getElementById(field).value = document.getElementById(field).value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    }
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
    else {        
      document.getElementById(cntfield).value = maxlimit - document.getElementById(field).value.length;
    }
}
```

also you were missing id `id="q17length"` in your html

edited: also u were not passing the ids as string: `textCounter('q17','q17length','500');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var tweet = prompt("Write Tweet:");

var tweetCount = tweet.length;

alert("You have written " + tweetCount + " characters, you have " + (140- tweetCount) + " Chartacters remaining")
```

Comment: You should add further explanation so readers (particularly learners) can understand the value of your answer compared to other solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new so sorry about that. I definitely will.