# Get position in div of highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the starting and ending position (number of characters) of my highlighted text including HTML.

Example:

```
<div class="container">    
<div id="test">
        Hello world, how <a href="#">are</a> you doing?
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to know example:

```
function startStop(){
    //
    // Do something here with selected text inside the DIV container
    //
    return {
        start: ???,
        stop: ???
    }
}
```

When I have selected: `how <a href="#">are</a> you` the output would be: `start = 30` and `stop = 57`

*note: so it starts counting from within the `container` div*

**UPDATE:**
When I use: `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset` it gives me the startOffset BUT inside the current element, I want it from the parent element.
So in my example it would output 6 if I have selected 'world' but I also need `<div id="test">` so the output needs to be: 21

Comment: "starting and ending postiion" - do you mean number of characters? or height/width position? It's a little confusing

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset will give you pixel coordinates. However, if you want the character position, you probably want [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @KyleR I mean "number of characters"

Comment: Do you want to count the whitespace? The HTML tags?

Comment: Hi, I want to know everything

Comment: Well, 'everything' will be a problem. The browser parses the HTML to generate the DOM, which includes trimming and compressing whitespace.

Comment: 'everything' won't return 30/29 in your example... 'everything' will return 38 ... since there are some leading spaces etc. so then you're example is wrong

Comment: Please see the update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function startStop(word){
    var start = $.trim($('#test')[0].innerHTML).indexOf(word);
    var stop = start + word.length;
    return {
        start: start,
        stop: stop
    }
}
```

the trim will make sure that all whitespaces etc are removed. Then we just check the index of the given word within the inner html to know the start. And the end equals the start + the length of the given word.

Note that it will return 29, not 30 because it starts with 0 ...

A small testcase can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/UQ2aC/

---

If you want the selected div included, you can use outerHTML instead of innerHTML (cfr. http://jsfiddle.net/UQ2aC/1/)

```
$.trim($('#test')[0].outerHTML).indexOf(word);
```

Note that you will have to make sure your html is nicely structured without spaces before your sentence in the div. Because this way, it will count these as well.

---

An alternative, if you really want to use 'dirty' html would be something like this:

```
$.trim($('#test')[0].outerHTML).indexOf('>') + $.trim($('#test')[0].innerHTML).indexOf('world') + 1
```

this will first count the length of the first tag itself, and add the length of the inner text without minding any spaces... (cfr. http://jsfiddle.net/UQ2aC/2/)

Comment: updated with all possibilities i could think of for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I'am not complete sure of what you are trying to archive, but if you want to count characters inside a div tag, maby this could help: [Javascript character count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962608/javascript-character-count)