# Show remaining characters for a text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Without editing the html file, I need to show what characters are remaining with a maximum of 300 chars.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="formRow clearfix">
            <span>
                <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                <label for="comments" id="charsLeft">(300)</label>
            </span>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have a function ready im not sure on what to have in the function for this to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text_max = 300;
    $('#charsLeft').html(text_max);

    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#charsLeft').html(text_remaining);
    });
});
```

I have searched the internet and other solutions to try resolve this but just cant seem to get it working. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the function you have so far. In general: (a) whenever the user changes the text box you should run a function, (b) that function should find out how many characters are in the text box, (c) and perform a calculation, and then (d) update another area on the page to show the result. Which part are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: You also have invalid markup.  You have a closing fieldset without an opening one.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962608/javascript-character-count

Comment: After the `<textarea>` and `<label>` exist add an _event listener_ to it for relevant _events_ where the _handler_ looks at the `.value.length` and does the desired action

Comment: Note that you may wish to add a [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) attribute on your `<textarea>` to add client-side, script-less enforcement of your maximum (but also check it on the server, as well).

Comment: I have edited the question with the current function i have, also this is just a snippet from my code the fieldset has an opening but just not shown

Comment: You should have tagged the question as jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
var holder = document.getElementById("charsLeft");
var commentsInput = document.getElementById("comments");

function updateRemainingCharacters() {

    var charsLeft = 300 - commentsInput.value.length;
    holder.innerText = "(" + charsLeft + ")";

}

commentsInput.addEventListener('keyup', updateRemainingCharacters);
commentsInput.addEventListener('paste', updateRemainingCharacters);
```